# Raw postscript (!ps) do not expand in argument of \psaxes

Tags: pstricks, ps, arguments

The `(!ps)` syntax is supposed to expand to a pair of coordinates by
executing some raw postscript code. In the following example it works well
in argument to `\rput` but not with `\psaxes`; why is it so?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}
\rput(! .5 .5 floor){floor level}
% \psaxes(! 0 .5 floor)(! 1 1) % fails with "Runaway argument?"
\psaxes(0,0)(1,1) % no trouble
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

More generally, is there a documentation giving details about the (!ps) syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the default behaviour! The coordinares are needed for the labels which are set on TeX level where the PostScript notation is not possible. You can create your own axes macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\def\psAxes(!#1 #2)(!#3 #4){\psline(!#1 0)(!#3 0)\psline(!0 #2)(!0 #4)}
\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}
    \rput(!.5 .5 floor){floor level}
    \psAxes(!0 {.5 floor})(!1 1) % fails with "Runaway argument?"
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but if I use `\psaxes` instead of two  `\psline` it is precisely to enjoy the automatic labeling. Actually I am not sure to understand the "... the labels which are set on TeX level..." part, because of lack of knowledge of internal TeX mechanism. Do you think that resorting to an auxiliary variable defined with `\pstFP*` arithmetic macros is the best (easiest) alternative? If so, I would provide it as an answer.

Comment: "on TeX level"  means that the labels are set by TeX and _not_ by PostScript. The coordinates defined by `(!...)` are evaluated when converting the ps output into pdf with `ps2pdf` or with `xdvipdfmx` when using `xelatex`. TeX does nothing with such coordinates. However, you can use any TeX macro to modify the coordinates.

Comment: Ok then, I'll accept this as an answer to the explicit question I asked. I wish there were a more elegant way than resorting to TeX arithmetic (or string parsing...). As for the concrete example I proposed, it seems that `\pstFPMul{\res}{\val}{1}` would perform a rounding towards zero of the expression in `\val` and store it in `\res`. This is the floor function if `\val`  is positive. Any *simple* idea for the general case is welcome.